# Use of "@import" when C++ modules are disabled @import FBSDKCoreKit error

Tags: c, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I exported a project from Unity, which included the Facebook SDK.
Build gives an

> "Use of "@import" when C++ modules are disabled

error in the files of Facebook SDK.

I have: **Xcode v11.1**; **Unity 2019.2.6f**; **Facebook SDK for Unity v7.18.0**;

I tried to build a project with these parameters, errors remain

[image: -fcxx-modules]

[image: Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)]

I will be grateful for your help!